# Why did the SharePoint event receiver stop firing?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a SharePoint 2010 solution. I have a List Definition and an event receiver associated with the definition. I have a list instance associated with the definition. The event receiver has a single method, ItemDeleting, that **was working for several days** up until some point yesterday.

I am working off my dev box, 2008R2, and am deploying directly from VS2010. When I set a breakpoint and delete an item on the list I never hit the break point. I built the package and deployed the solution to a demo box and the event receiver does fire there just not on my dev box any longer. I have dropped the content database and restored and tried a few other things but the event still will not fire.

Where should I look to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar issue happen where a click event never made it to the handler just as if the event had been swallowed.  In my case, I finally found that an exception had been thrown which short-circuited the event.

**Check for a exception being thrown somewhere.**

Comment: The list item is being deleted so shouldn't the event fire and it is working when deployed to the demo server?

Comment: Hmmm, my next guess would be that the handler chain is messed up in your dev host. Try creating a new instance of the list and seeing if the event fires for it? Next try it in a different site, and then in a different site collection - in case the trouble is with the feature registration at a given level.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the DLL that contains the Event Receiver is located in the GAC.
It could be a deployment problem.
Have a look at the "manifest.xml".